# rospy: node namespace is empty

Tags: ros, rospy, namespace, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the impression that a node per default has a namespace matching the node name.

Mini example, I run this node:

```
import rospy

rospy.init_node('tester')
rospy.set_param('foo', 1)
rospy.spin()
```

I then run `rosparam list`, I get:

```
/foo
/rosdistro
/roslaunch/uris/host_knxps13_local__35409
/rosversion /run_id
```

Why don't I get:

```
 /tester/foo
```

Why is the namespace of the node `/` and not `/tester`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282943/rospy:-node-namespace-is-empty/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer. `rospy` nodes do not have a direct equivalent to `roscpp` `ros::NodeHandle`.

See (almost) duplicate question and answer - including way to resolve names relative to a rospy node's name - [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/261862/rospy-equivalent-to-rosnodehandle-nhnamespace/?answer=261999#post-id-261999).

---

Edit:
Yes, for rospy, in order to have `rosparam list` generate this:

```
/tester/foo     
/rosdistro     
/roslaunch/uris/host_knxps13_local__35409     
/rosversion   
/run_id
```

You will need to set the `foo` as a private parameter of the `tester` rospy node:

```
import rospy

rospy.init_node('tester')
rospy.set_param('~foo', 1)
rospy.spin()
```

---

Additional info:
http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server
http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters
http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Resolving

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-02-16**:
Thanks for a quick reply!
The `resolve_name` seems to work only for private parameters:

```
value = rospy.set_param('~bar', 'zzz')
rospy.loginfo('%s has value %s', rospy.resolve_name('~bar'), value)
```

... but does not work without the `~`.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-02-16**:
@knxa That is correct. When you call `rospy.resolve_name('~bar')`, you are telling ROS, "Give me the global name of relative name `~bar`" - in this case `/tester/bar`. If you were to call
`rospy.set_param('foo', 1)`, then `rospy.resolve_name('foo')` would return `/foo`...

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-02-16**:
since `/` is the namespace in which the relative parameter name `foo` was declared. If you were to launch `tester` in another namespace `ns1` (via roslaunch), then `rospy.resolve_name('~bar')` would return `/ns1/tester/bar` and `rospy.resolve_name('food')` would return `/ns1/foo`

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-02-16**:
[The ROS Wiki has a pretty thorough explanation of ROS name resolution](http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Resolving)